# Is there any API to access iPhone or Android music library in trigger IO

Tags: android, iphone, trigger.io

I am working with trigger io application . I have just made one functionality to access the videos and images from iPhone/Android gallery . I have used the file API for that  like :

```
forge.file.getImage
```

and

```
forge.file.getVideo
```

but I am not getting any API for accessing music . what all I can achieve is to access the music file from the src folder . but I want to access music from the phone library . Is there any support added in the trigger IO ? or is there any external library doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Trigger doesn't provide a module that would allow this, it would be possible however to implement your own native module to expose that functionality.

See https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html for documentation on writing native modules.